# How can I find a pattern in this statement to find the CO2 emissions

Tags: python, spacy

Which pattern could I use to identify this paragraph or only the relevant sentence using spacy in Python for a report?

"Our total Scope 1 and Scope 2 GHG
emissions for 2019 were 2.6 million metric tons, resulting
in a GHG intensity factor of 0.014 metric tons of CO2e per
million cubic feet equivalent of production."

I tried using a pattern which used this, but it does not seem to work:

```
    pattern = [
       {'IS_DIGIT': True},
       {'LOWER': '(million metric tons)'},
       ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For patterns like the one you've given here, each dictionary in the pattern has to correspond to one token, but `(million metric tons)` is not going to be one token, so it will never match anything.

What you could do is use a phrase pattern, which uses literal text, to give `(million metric tons)` an entity label like `UNIT`, and then use a different entity ruler component after that to match a digits token followed by a `UNIT` entity.

I would suggest you take the time to read through the whole [rule-based matching section](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching) in the spaCy docs, which will explain the difference between token and phrase patterns.